# Access to SMB folder from LocalService account

Tags: file-permissions, user-permissions, synology, tomcat8, service-accounts

this is the situation:
I have a Synology server with file folder normally accessible from the windows domain computers;
I also have onto the primary domain server an application built onto Apache Tomcat 8.5 which runs with "local service" account.
Inside this app, I cannot access path that points to the synology folder, although I have setted "Everyone R/W" on the security tab of the data folder.
I guess the "Localservice" account does not have enough privileges to write into the data folder, am I right?
What is the simplest way to access those folders? Should I use another account, maybe a domain account, to run the Apache service?